# Issue with SQL Server 2019 SSMS connection

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server 2019 Express installation. It was acting weird in that even though I had set it to mixed mode auth, I could not change the `sa` password (I know we shouldn't use this, but it's a requirement for an app) because my enterprise admin account was not a sysadmin.

So, I read a bunch of articles, but nothing helped, so since there was no data yet, I tried a reinstall, which didn't help and then uninstalled SQL Server, rebooted and reinstalled again.

This time, I could connect as `sa` or Windows auth using SSMS, but only if I append `,1433` to the `server\db name` in the SSMS connection window else I get the 26 error. I have read and checked all the fixes, the instance is not hidden, made the firewall rules, etc., but none of these things help.

I am tempted to delete the whole VM at this point and start over, but that's tedious.

Comment: By default Express is a named instances and runs on a dynamic port. Omitting the name would mean the default instance name. Perhaps before you used thr name MSSQLSERVER and this time forgot to change it from SQLEXPRESS?

Comment: It is the same for MSSQLSERVER.  I have to use ,1433 login as well.

Comment: I feel like there's something else going on here we're not being told. The default port is 1433, so omitting the port would direct the connection to that port.

Comment: _error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified_? Instance names are resolved using SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) requests via the SQL Browser service listening on udp/1434 on the target machine. Is the SQL Browser service installed? Is the SQL Browser service running? Did you restart it after reinstalling (and renaming) the SQL Server instance?